# How can I import functions from other folders in Python project?

Tags: python, module, project

I cannot import the functions from other packages in my Python project.

[image: Project structure]

As suggested, I added

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../ExportExcel'))
from ExportExcel.export_excel import export_excel
```

at the beginning of the clip_finder.py.
I also put

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

inside the export_excel.py.

Inside ExportExcel.**init**.py I put

```
from .export_excel import export_excel
```

However I still get this error:

```
C:\Main\SupportScripts\ClipFinder>python clip_finder.py -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Main\SupportScripts\ClipFinder\clip_finder.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ExportExcel.export_excel import export_excel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ExportExcel'
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: in your modules (the one you want to import) make sure to export the functions in that modules `__init__.py` file

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen how do I do that?

Comment: I added 'from .export_excel import export_excel' to ExportExcel.__init__.py, but it did not help...

Comment: OP, read [this](https://stackabuse.com/creating-and-importing-modules-in-python/) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and [this](https://stackabuse.com/python-modules-creating-importing-and-sharing/) and [this](https://www.guru99.com/import-module-python.html)